# Is there a race condition to remove the elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to JS and HTML. I would like to remove an element from the page as soon as the page is loaded. This is my simple HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id="trapParent"><a id="trap" href='/trap/removeByJS'> Javascript removal </a></div>
        <script>
        function timeout() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                timeout();
            }, 1000);
        }
        timeout();
        var parent = document.getElementById('trapParent');
        var child = document.getElementById('trap');
        while (child & parent){
        parent.removeChild(child);
        parent = undefined;
        child = undefined;
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I open the page I can still get a reference to the link on the page; when I get the value of `document.getElementById('trap');`, it returns the link which means that it is still in the DOM and I can see that the link is still there. Am I missing something here?

I added the timeout function to make sure that the script will run after the page is loaded.

Comment: you cant block main thread with setTimeout, its async, you need promise to do that. Also change child & parent to child && parent if you're checking if they are defined

Comment: How can I remove the element then? because if it is not loaded, then document.getElementById('trap'); would be nothing.

Comment: change child & parent to child && parent worked for me, you dont really need the settimeout. js is going to run after page loads because its at the bottom of body

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load). If you remove the element in an onLoad function you should be fine.

Comment: Nice, thanks, guys! remove onload worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to above answers, the following worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body onload = "removelink();">
        <div id="trapParent"><a id="trap" href='/trap/removeByJS'> disables Javascript </a></div>

        Hey!
         <script>
        function removelink( ){
                var parent = document.getElementById('trapParent');
                var child = document.getElementById('trap');
                while (child && parent){
                        parent.removeChild(child);
                        parent = undefined;
                        child = undefined;
                }
        }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```